# Take a link that ends "default.aspx?ID=4" and pass the value 4 as a parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010

On my main page of my website, I post elements from one table in my database. If I click on one of the elements, it takes me to a page based on the ID of that record. For example, on my default.aspx page, I list records from my table using a datalist control. Each record acts as a hyperlink and takes you to Places.aspx?ID=(record number). Now, each of these pages need to be able to insert comments specific to that page. I've got a comment box set up and working well. I can even make it pull up comments that are specific to that page. My problem is trying to make the page insert a comment for that specific page. I assume I need to be able to use the record number passed from the default.aspx page that was used to create the places.aspx?ID=(record number) page. Here is my code behind for places.aspx:

```
protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\TravelJoansDB.accdb;";
    string cmdstr = "INSERT INTO Comments(commentText,datePosted,personName,postID) VALUES (@txtComments, @datePosted, @personName, @postID)";
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con);
    TextBox tComments = (TextBox)FormView1.FindControl("txtComments");
    HiddenField tDate = (HiddenField)FormView1.FindControl("hidTimeDate");
    TextBox tName = (TextBox)FormView1.FindControl("txtName");

    con.Open();
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtComments", tComments.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datePosted", DateTime.Now.ToString());
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@personName", tName.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postID",
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

I realize the code isn't finished, but that's where I'd like ya'lls help. (Yes, I'm from the southern part of the United States. I don't even know what type of variable I should declare, whether it be a integer or what.

And here is the ASP:

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server" 
        DataFile="~/App_Data/TravelJoansDB.accdb" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Comments] WHERE postID=@ID"
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Comments] (commentText, datePosted, personName, postID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)" >
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ID" QueryStringField="ID" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="commentText" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="datePosted" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="personName" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
    </asp:AccessDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `int.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"])`

If it isn't in the querystring, or if it isn't an integer, this will throw an exception.